# Javascript AngularJS: Inner function cannot the variable value of outer function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sqlite, cordova

I am developing ionic hybrid application. I am using $http to get value from server. Next, I will make a cordova sqlite query, inside the cordova query I want to insert my result from $http call from server and result of cordova query into my sqlite database. However, I can't get the value of $http return value in my cordova query. The following is my code:

```
$http({
    method: "post",
    url: "http://localhost/php2/get_channel.php",
    data: {
        user_name: usernameID
    },
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
}).success(function(response) {
    for(i=0; i<response.length; i++){
        var channelNameQuery = "SELECT * FROM chat_friend WHERE channel_id=?"
        var channelNamePromise = $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, channelNameQuery, [response[i].ChannelName]).then(function (result){
            var ChannelQuery = "REPLACE INTO chat_channel (last_text, usernameID, chat_channel, chat_channel_name) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
            $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, ChannelQuery, [response[i].LastText, usernameID,  response[i].ChannelName, result.rows.item(0).UserName]);
        })
    }
}).error(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    console.log("failed");
});
```

I can't get response[i].LastText and response[i].ChannelName value inside  $cordovaSQLite.execute() function.

Sorry for my poor language.

Comment: Show us **response** json data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you recive is mapped on `response.data`. Try looping thru your data by using `angular.forEach()`. Remember that `response` is mostly a object so you cant get `response.length` here. Please take a look at the [$http AngularJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

```
$http({
    method: "post",
    url: "http://localhost/php2/get_channel.php",
    data: {
        user_name: usernameID
    },
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
}).success(function(response) {
    angular.forEach(response.data, function (data) {
        var channelNameQuery = "SELECT * FROM chat_friend WHERE channel_id=?"
        var channelNamePromise = $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, channelNameQuery, [data.ChannelName]).then(function (result){
            var ChannelQuery = "REPLACE INTO chat_channel (last_text, usernameID, chat_channel, chat_channel_name) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
            $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, ChannelQuery, [data.LastText, usernameID, data.ChannelName, result.rows.item(0).UserName]);
        })
    });
}).error(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    console.log("failed");
});
```